# My same as function not duplicating data from input fields

Tags: html, laravel

when your physical and postal address is the same then you should be able to click the same button and the data fields from the postal should become the same as the physical address to auto complete the postal address. if it is not the same then you should be able to insert data manually.

```js
     $("#sameas").click(function(){
                var res_unit = $("#res_unit").val();
                var red_complex = $("#red_complex").val();
                var address_1 = $("#address_1").val();
                var address_2 = $("#address_2").val();
                var suburb = $("#suburb").val();
                var city = $("#city").val();
                var province = $("#province").val();
                var code = $("#code").val();

                $("#pst_unit").val(res_unit);
                $("#pst_complex").val(red_complex);
                $("#postal_address_1").val(address_1);
                $("#postal_address_2").val(address_2);
                $("#postal_suburb").val(suburb);
                $("#postal_city").val(city);
                $("#postal_province").val(province);
                $("#postal_code").val(code);

            });
```

```css
    #sameas {
                width: 20em;  height: 2em;
            }
```

```html
     <h4>Physical Address</h4>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md">
                            {!!Form::text('res_unit', 'Unit Number')!!}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md">
                            {!!Form::text('red_complex', 'Complex')!!}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md">
                            {!!Form::text('address_1', 'Street Number')!!}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md">
                            {!!Form::text('address_2', 'Street Name')!!}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md">
                            {!!Form::text('suburb', 'Suburb')!!}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md">
                            {!!Form::text('city', 'City')!!}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            {!!Form::select('province', 'Province',Config::get('constants.Provinces'))!!}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            {!!Form::text('code', 'Code')!!}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <h4>Postal Address</h4>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='button' id="sameas" class="btn" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 10px;background-color: #b02c22fc;color: white;" value="Same as physical address" >
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md">
                            {!!Form::text('pst_unit', 'Unit Number')!!}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md">
                            {!!Form::text('pst_complex', 'Complex')!!}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md">
                            {!!Form::text('postal_address_1', 'Street Number')!!}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md">
                            {!!Form::text('postal_address_2', 'Street Name')!!}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md">
                            {!!Form::text('postal_suburb', 'Suburb')!!}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md">
                            {!!Form::text('postal_city', 'City')!!}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            {!!Form::select('postal_province', 'Province',Config::get('constants.Provinces'))!!}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            {!!Form::text('postal_code', 'Code')!!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I have tried to chance the script but to no avail. it is as if the script don not see where it should be implemented and therefore not in use. Also i cant get Laravel to work in snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Check the generated HTML, does it have an **id** attribute on each field? I can almost bet it doesn't.

That's because the `Form::text()` helper function doesn't assign an id by default.

You need to either:

1. Use the `Form::label()` function before the input, as explained over here: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#labels

or

2. Add it on as an attribute on the function as you would with a class:

   `Form::text('code', 'Code', ['id' => 'code'])`

Comment: for this function i should be able to do this only with one id "sameas" and  the  attribute for example "#pst_unit" does not need to have an id as the attribute is unique and therefore it is its own id .

Comment: Then your code is wrong, $("#res_unit").val(); won't ever find anything if you don't put the id on the field. You should be asking how to select a specific input inside an html object instead.

Comment: Thank you i found the problem the view did not see my script i did not add it properly. @Erubiel i upvoted your comment and the answer.